# Gnuplot: how to set xrange with set xtics time?

Tags: gnuplot, xrange

I plot a time-series of datas (images, throughput), using this:

```
set term postscript color eps enhanced 22
set encoding utf8
set output "tput.eps"
load "../styles.inc"
set size 1,0.6
set bmargin 4.5
set tmargin 2.5
set lmargin 9
set rmargin 8
set title "{/bold Images updated and generated network traffic}" offset 0,0
set ylabel "#Images" offset 0,0
set y2label "Throughput [GB/day]" offset -2,0
set ytics 0,100,800
set ytics nomirror

set y2tics 0,100,600
set y2tics nomirror

set xtics time
set format x '%d/%m/%Y'

set grid y
set yrange[0:800]
set y2range [0:]
set xtics rotate by 45 right font "Arial, 18" nomirror
set key vertical sample 1.0 maxrows 1 width -0.6 at graph 1,1.13 font "Arial, 18"

set datafile separator ","
plot "datecount_sorted.csv" using (timecolumn(1, "%Y-%m-%d")):($2) with lines ls 5001 title "Uploaded images",\
     "datecount_sorted.csv" using (timecolumn(1, "%Y-%m-%d")):($3/(1024*1024*1024)) axis x1y2 ls 5002 title "Upload Throughput",\
                     
!epstopdf "tput.eps"
!rm "tput.eps"
quit
```

The input data looks like this:

```
2016-04-12,1,0
2016-05-02,2,0
2016-05-05,2,0
2016-05-06,1,0
2016-05-11,2,0
2016-05-13,3,0
2016-05-25,2,0
2016-06-01,3,541204241
2016-06-06,1,0
2016-06-13,1,471311979
2016-06-14,1,6329289
2016-06-17,1,137972881
2016-06-24,1,319050239
2016-06-27,1,138193384
```

The output is correct, it looks like this:
[image]

The problem is that when I try to set an xrange, the plot breaks completely (does not render).
This syntax in particular seems to be wrong:

```
set xrange ["2020-01-01":"2020-06-17"]
```

And similarly wrong is the one using the same timefmt that is used in the plot:

```
set xrange ["01/01/2020":"17/06/2020"]
```

So..what is the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is `set xdata time` and `set timefmt <format string>` to tell gnuplot how read the dates from the data, the xrange is set using the format specified in `timefmt`, which doesn't have to be the same as the `format` you give to the axis, the plot breaks because it can't decode the dates from the xrange.
In your case adding this should suffice

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y/%m/%d"
```

I tested it with `set xrange ["2016/04/12":"2016/05/03"]` on the example data file you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You must explicitely parse the time strings passed to the range settings:

```
set xtics time
FMT="%Y-%m-%d"
set format x "%d/%m/%Y"
set xrange [strptime(FMT, "2016-01-01"):strptime(FMT, "2016-06-17")]

set datafile separator commna   
plot "datecount_sorted.csv" using (timecolumn(1, FMT)):2 with lines title "Uploaded images"
```

Comment: Are you sure? As I am using `timecolumn(1, "%Y-%m-%d")`  I though the `set timeft` was somehow deprecated.

Comment: The `set  timefmt` is not deprecated, AFAIK. The timecolumn offers more flexibility when using different time formats. But for some reason, my first version with `set timefmt` didn't work. So you must manually parse the time string passed to the settings.